# Adding to and deleting hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, sorting

I am trying to create the back-end for a calendar system. The calendar is just a list of `Event`s. I am trying to organise this in to a reasonable JSON response. The structure I am looking to replicate would be something like this

```
eventsList = [
  { 'year' => 2014,
     'events' => [{event data hash 1}, 
                  {event data hash 2}]
  },
  { 'year' => 2015,
     'events' => [{event data hash 1}, 
                  {event data hash 2}]
  }
]
```

I am having trouble trying to add events to the right array. Below I have `Event.all` and I am trying to sort the list.

```
events = Event.all
eventList = []

events.each do |event|
    #Creates a hash of the current event info
    eventInfo = {'description' => event.description, 'startdate' => event.startdate}
    
    eventMonthNumber = event.startdate.strftime('%m').to_i
    eventMonthName = event.startdate.strftime('%B')
    eventYearNumber = event.startdate.strftime('%Y').to_i

    # Adds year to eventList if it isn't present
    unless eventList.include?(eventYearNumber)
        eventList << {'year' => eventYearNumber, 'events' => []}
    end

    # Tries to find current year hash in array and add to event key
    currentYear =  eventList.select {|event| event['year'] == eventYearNumber}
    currentYear['events'] << eventInfo
end
```

I get the error `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`. I am not entirely sure whether the `eventList.select` is the correct way to go about this

Comment: What's the data type of `event['year']`?

Comment: I did a calendar system about a yr ago https://github.com/mzaragoza/rails-fullcalendar-icecube  when a event gets added/deleted I make a new call to a json take a look and I hope it helps

Comment: @PrakashMurthy It's an integer

Comment: @MZaragoza That's really nice, I checked out the demo, I'll take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have moved away from this current structure the change that made it work was swapping out

```
 eventList.select
```

For

```
 eventList.detect
```

Select returns an array (?) And detect returns one item.